# Create and Run consecutive Tasks in list

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task

I have a `Dictionary< string, Action[] >` , and i want to create a list of tasks and i have write this code to create this list of tasks that will be execute consecutively.

```
var TaskList = new List<Task>();

     foreach (var item in this.Values) {
        if (TaskList.Count == 0) {
           var task = new Task(item[0]);
           var LogAct = task.ContinueWith((t) => item[1](), this.TokenCanc, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion, TaskScheduler.Default);
           TaskList.AddRange(new[] { task, LogAct });
        }
        else {
           var task = TaskList[TaskList.Count - 1].ContinueWith((t) => item[0](), this.TokenCanc, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion, TaskScheduler.Default);
           var LogAct = task.ContinueWith((t) => item[1](), this.TokenCanc, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion, TaskScheduler.Default);
           TaskList.AddRange(new[] { task, LogAct });            
        }
     }
     return TaskList;
  }
```

now after this, to start my consecutive Tasks i call:

```
TaskList[0].Start();
```

I would have expected that the execution starts from 1° task to latest task but unfortunately it is not so.

Example:

I Add Actions to my Dictionary:

```
 ActionsLog.Add("T1", new Action[] { () => {
    Console.WriteLine("Test1");Thread.Sleep(2000);}, () => Console.WriteLine("LogTest1") });
 ActionsLog.Add("T2", new Action[] { () => {
    Console.WriteLine("Test2");Thread.Sleep(2000);}, () => Console.WriteLine("LogTest2") });
 ActionsLog.Add("T3", new Action[] { () => {
    Console.WriteLine("Test3");Thread.Sleep(2000);}, () => Console.WriteLine("LogTest3") });
 ActionsLog.Add("T4", new Action[] { () => {
    Console.WriteLine("Test4");Thread.Sleep(2000);}, () => Console.WriteLine("LogTest4") });
 ActionsLog.Add("T5", new Action[] { () => {
    Console.WriteLine("Test5");Thread.Sleep(2000);}, () => Console.WriteLine("LogTest5") });
 ActionsLog.Add("T6", new Action[] { () => {
    Console.WriteLine("Test6"); Thread.Sleep(2000); }, () => Console.WriteLine("LogTest6") });
```

After TaskList[0].Start() I obtain output:

```
Test1
LogTest6
Test6
LogTest6
Test6
LogTest6
Test6
LogTest6
Test6
LogTest6
Test6
LogTest6
```

I probably have not taken the right way , but how can I solve my problem ?

Comment: Looks like it's a closure problem. But I can't reproduce it. Can you provide information about your .net/compiler/JIT versions?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish here. Why don't you use `await` instead of a chain of continuations, for example? And if you want help, add code that we can actually run and test, and that displays your issue.

Comment: hi thanks, but i'm using 4.5 framework

Comment: At first I thought it was a closure problem, but I've tried to reproduce it the closest possible to your code, and I can't definitely reproduce: https://dotnetfiddle.net/31mRfE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a closure problem. 
Check out your compiler.
In old versions `foreach` loop keep reference to last delegate.
So for example this code will print `3 3 3` for old compiler versions and `1 2 3` for new.

```
var numbers = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
var actions = new List<Action>();
foreach (var number in numbers)
    actions.Add(() => Console.WriteLine(number));
foreach (var action in actions)
    action();
```

To avoid this, you should have compiler with higher version than `4.0.30319.1` if you use MS compiler and higher than `2.4.4` if you use Mono.
You can find more info [here](https://github.com/AndreyAkinshin/ItDepends.NET/tree/master/ClosureAndForeach) and [here](http://problembook.net/content/en/Linq/ClosureAndForeach-S.html).

Comment: Yes!!!! with your code the result with my compiler is 3,3,3!!!! I have Read the solution and work, after a post my Correct Code! Thank you!! :D

Comment: Hi! yes this is the solution! i have v4.0.303191 compiler version and i have the problem that you told me! i will publish the correct code to solve the problem! thak you!!!

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you want to do, but

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>{
    foreach(var action in this.Values.SelectMany(x=>x))
        action();
});
```

Hope it helps.

OR maybe

> ```
>         var d = new Dictionary<string,Action[]>();
>         var origin = new Task(() => { });
>         var runner = origin;
>         foreach (var action in d.Values.SelectMany(x=>x))
>         {
>             runner = runner.ContinueWith(prev => action());
>         }
>
>         origin.Start();
> ```

Ok, complete working sample. Just Copy and Paste.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var ActionsLog = new Dictionary<string, Action[]>();

            ActionsLog.Add("T1", new Action[]
            {
                () =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Test1");
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                },
                () => Console.WriteLine("LogTest1")
            });
            ActionsLog.Add("T2", new Action[] { () => {
                    Console.WriteLine("Test2");Thread.Sleep(2000);}, () => Console.WriteLine("LogTest2") });
            ActionsLog.Add("T3", new Action[] { () => {
                    Console.WriteLine("Test3");Thread.Sleep(2000);}, () => Console.WriteLine("LogTest3") });
            ActionsLog.Add("T4", new Action[] { () => {
                    Console.WriteLine("Test4");Thread.Sleep(2000);}, () => Console.WriteLine("LogTest4") });
            ActionsLog.Add("T5", new Action[] { () => {
                    Console.WriteLine("Test5");Thread.Sleep(2000);}, () => Console.WriteLine("LogTest5") });
            ActionsLog.Add("T6", new Action[]
            {
                () =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Test6");
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                },
                () => Console.WriteLine("LogTest6")
            });




            var origin = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { });
            var runner = origin;
            foreach (var action in ActionsLog.Values.SelectMany(x => x))
            {
                runner = runner.ContinueWith(prev => action());
            }

            origin.Wait();


            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Final.
Exlude execution logic in separate func

> ```
>     public static void ExecuteActions(Action[] actions)
>     {
>         var origin = new Task(() => { });
>         var runner = origin;
>         foreach (var action in actions)
>         {
>             runner = runner.ContinueWith(prev => action());
>         }
>
>         origin.Start();
>         origin.Wait();
>     }
> ```

and try to call it with different Action arrays. It should work. If it doesnt working for you, so you have problem with your data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I Want to create a contiguous tasks execution using .ContinueWith method from First task added in list.

Comment: Not Work :( I try your method but i always Execute the latest Action in d.Values.... Same as my problem... :(

Comment: Thank you! i copy/paste your code... but same result as before :(

Comment: if you are creating Task via constructor (var t = new Task()) - so you need to call start. If you are creating Task via factory (Task.Factory.Startnew()) - you dont need to call Start, its starts automatically.

Comment: Check what exactly contains inside your dictionary. Probably problem in your data.

Comment: i don't understand why i should only execute the lastest action :(

Comment: I have re-try your code.. but the output is the same for all actions : LogTest6LogTest6LogTest6LogTest6LogTest6LogTest6LogTest6

Comment: probably problem in your data, not in Task logic.

Answer (score 0):

I did almost the same and it works..

```
void Main()
{
var actionlog = new Dictionary<string, Action[]>();
actionlog.Add("T1", new Action[] { () => {
                Console.WriteLine("Test1");Thread.Sleep(2000);}, () => Console.WriteLine("LogTest1") });
actionlog.Add("T2", new Action[] { () => {
                Console.WriteLine("Test2");Thread.Sleep(2000);}, () => Console.WriteLine("LogTest2") });
actionlog.Add("T3", new Action[] { () => {
                Console.WriteLine("Test3");Thread.Sleep(2000);}, () => Console.WriteLine("LogTest3") });
actionlog.Add("T4", new Action[] { () => {
                Console.WriteLine("Test4");Thread.Sleep(2000);}, () => Console.WriteLine("LogTest4") });
actionlog.Add("T5", new Action[] { () => {
                Console.WriteLine("Test5");Thread.Sleep(2000);}, () => Console.WriteLine("LogTest5") });
actionlog.Add("T6", new Action[] { () => {
                Console.WriteLine("Test6"); Thread.Sleep(2000); }, () => Console.WriteLine("LogTest6") });

var task = GetTaskChain(actionlog);

task.Start();
}

public Task GetTaskChain(Dictionary<string, Action[]> actionlog)
{
CancellationToken token = new CancellationToken();
var TaskList = new List<Task>();

foreach (var item in actionlog.Values)
{
    if (TaskList.Count == 0)
    {
        var task = new Task(item[0]);
        var LogAct = task.ContinueWith((t) => item[1](), token, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion, TaskScheduler.Default);
        TaskList.AddRange(new[] { task, LogAct });
    }
    else
    {
        var task = TaskList[TaskList.Count - 1].ContinueWith((t) => item[0](), token, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion, TaskScheduler.Default);
        var LogAct = task.ContinueWith((t) => item[1](), token, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion, TaskScheduler.Default);
        TaskList.AddRange(new[] { task, LogAct });
    }
}
return TaskList[0];
}
```

Comment: Here is my Output: Test1
LogTest1
Test2
LogTest2
Test3
LogTest3
Test4
LogTest4
Test5
LogTest5
Test6
LogTest6

Comment: LogTest6
Test6
LogTest6
Test6
LogTest6
Test6
LogTest6

Answer (score 0):

I have the solution that Kote suggest me.

With compiler version v4.0.303191 , the problem is "ClosureAndForeach". 
The code Solution is:

```
var list = new List<Action>();
     foreach (int i in Enumerable.Range(1, 10)) {
        DisplayClass c = new DisplayClass();
        c.i = i;
        list.Add(c.getAct());
     }
     foreach (Action action in list)
        action();
```

and the code of sealed class..

```
private sealed class DisplayClass {
     public int i;

     public Action getAct() {
        return () => Console.WriteLine(i);
     }
     public void Action() {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
     }
  }
```

Thanks All!